# How to add index page in curl page in android please guide me

Tags: java, android

How to add index page in curl pages in android? Please guide me about curl page. Already I edited according my requirement. I need an add index  page in curl. Can you just send me some code?

Comment: Please describe what you already tried, also have look at: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: We do not just send you code in SO. We help you with your code. If you show us what you have we can help you get it working and explain the problems, but this is not a code writing service. You can add some code to your question by using the [edit] button.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can find your solution in this link
https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl